# Append Some text to each table header (th) using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, append

I am trying to add append some inside each th. Table header is Dynamic Generated depend on Database Column

Here's what I have:

```
<table id="dynamic_id" class="table table-striped  table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
         //body goes here
    </tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**What is Expect** using jQuery on Ready Event.

```
 <th>Company Name   
           <span class="js-sorter-desc fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></span> 
           <span class="js-sorter-asc  fa fa-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
 </th>
```

This should be apply on Each Th ..

```
<span class="js-sorter-desc fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
<span class="js-sorter-asc  fa fa-chevron-up pull-right">
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, including looking through[the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com), and try to do the work. **If** you run into a *specific* problem, after more thorough research and [searching](/help/searching) here on-site, if you cannot resolve it, post your attempt along with the trouble you're having with it. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Count number of column using if table is dynamic and then append what ever you want to inside th using each

Comment: So what have you actually tried? I'm not seeing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `append` **jquery** method.

Also, use `find` method in order to get all `th` **DOM** elements.

```js
$('.table.table-striped').find('thead tr th').append('<span class="js-sorter-desc fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></span><span class="js-sorter-asc  fa fa-chevron-up pull-right"></span>');
console.log($('.table.table-striped').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dynamic_id" class="table table-striped  table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
         //body goes here
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't need `each()` here

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for your point ! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').find('th')append('<span class="js-sorter-desc fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></span><span class="js-sorter-asc  fa fa-chevron-up pull-right">');
});
```

Comment: You don't need `each()` here. Also the whole point is that the `id` is dynamically generated at runtime, so selecting by it would probably not work.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, I have updated my answer. I have used `each` to have dynamic code. I know as he wants to add to all `<th>` so we can simply consider it as a selector.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but you still don't need the `each()` 'dynamic' or not

Comment: I removed `each()` now. You are the man. Thanks :-)